# Delete Table Row Interop Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, tablerow

I've been playing around with this, but I just can't get it to work. I have a table in Microsoft Word, and in this table is a mailmerge field which my C# program selects.

I'd like to delete the row which contains the field. I tried this:

```
app.Selection.SelectRow();
app.Selection.Delete();
```

Where `app` is an instance `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application`.

As written, this code deletes the text inside the table, but leaves an empty table row behind. How can I delete the table row itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a Range or Selection, in most cases you can address the "containing" level like this:

```
app.Selection.Rows[1]
```

(Since I'm on a mobile device I can't check whether you can use .Delete() directly or whether you need .Range.Delete())

Similarly, Selection.Tables[1] would pick up the table around the selection and Selection.Paragraphs[1] the paragraph around the selection.

Note that, unless what you want to do simply won't work any other way, you should use the Range object. There will be less screen-flicker, execution will be faster and your code more predictable.

Comment: This is perfect! Follow up question: is there a way to access the row below the selection if I am unsure if it already exists? I.e. I want to select the row below or add a row.  (Maybe wishful thinking)

Comment: Sure. Something along the lines of: app.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[app.Selection.Rows[1].Index + 1].Select(); Although when things reach this level of complexity I'd tend to create objects for the table, the row(s), etc. In the Office object models dot-notation is 1) not efficient and 2) in the .NET Framework environment will tend to create COM objects with pointers that can cause problems because you won't be able to properly release them.